# Android Studio dynamically add textfield with diffrent type of edittext

Tags: android, text, field

I was looking for solution, how can I add a field on screen, after tap by finger? Where user can dynamically add any kind of text, which will stay on screen.

I was looking for any examples but I failed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add MotionEventListener to a view-> get coordinates where on screen a tap accured --> add an editText at thoes coordinates and change it to textView when done editig the text (You can use ViewSwitcher for that)